# Popup menu comes out in left bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

I am trying to implement popup menu in my fragment but the result is far beyond my desire. I have a button on the action bar and one of these buttons call the popup menu and no problem till here. It successfully calls and I can see the popup menu. Here is how I do that.

In fragment class

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.x) {           
    } else showPopup(view /* or getView() */);

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);
    MenuInflater menuInflater = popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.event_popup, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

popup_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/a"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    android:title="a" />

<item android:id="@+id/b"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    android:title="b" />
```

Fragment's action menu (includes button which opens popup menu)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/x"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="" />

<item android:id="@+id/y"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_menu_dot"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="" />

</menu>
```

And in the result here is how it looks. I want it to be on top right. How can I handle this. As far as I know, Its default placement is already top right.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide proper anchor view (overflow menu in this case) to the popup menu.

Try changing

```
showPopup(view);
```

to

```
View menuItemView = MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.overflow_menu); // replace with your id
showPopup(menuItemView);
```

This should bring the popup menu to top. If its still on the left side use

```
popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.END);
```

Comment: What is R.id.overflow_menu here? My popup xml? It expects id in this case not menu.

Comment: that should be the id of the view you are tapping to open the popup menu, possibly the overflow menu icon id on action bar.